# OleDbDataAdapter Query

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

Here's my code
I want to display specific data from database but I hv no idea about the query

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class balance
    Public id3 As String = ""

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub balance_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        id3 = Menu1.id2
        Dim sql As OleDbCommand
        sql = New OleDbCommand("select USER_BALANCE from USERLOGIN where USER_LOGIN = '" & id3 & "'")
        OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Result show me all my data from database but I wanted to show only specific data

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You need to edit the question to clarify. Worse, what code you have shown is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: I got 2 user data in database , I wanted to show only specific user data but result gave me both user data

Comment: Stop the code in debug mode and see what is the value of id3. Copy your query from the debugger into your database management environment and see what is the outcome.

Comment: id3 was my txt_id.Text from other form , I had set it as variables and pass it to this form , but It still unable to query